# Magento: Using custom variables in a layout file

Tags: magento

Is it possible to use `Custom Variables` in a layout file? I can use them in a template file like this:

```
Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('variableCode')->getData('store_plain_value')
```

But not sure with the xml file.

I know I could use the above instead, but this would be useful to know anyway for future uses too.

> **UPDATE:** Have been most unclear I'm afraid. I am specifically looking to access the admin panel "Custom Variables" section, not just pass my own variables to a block. I do apologise for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the updated question:

Create a helper class which wraps the `core/variable` functionality, e.g:

```
class Some_Module_Helper_Variable
{
    public function getVariableData($code,$param)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode($code)->getData($param);
    }
}
```

Then, in layout XML for your block you can do this (I believe):

```
<action method="setSomeVal">
    <arg helper="class_group/variable/getVariableData">
        <arg1>variableCode</arg1>
        <arg2>store_plain_value</arg2>
    </arg>
</action>
```

Comment: just to mention: when you use multiple store views its good to add this:

`Mage::getModel('core/variable')->setstoreid(Mage::app()->getstore()->getid())->loadByCode($code)->getData($param)`

Answer (score 5):

`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` extends `Varien_Object` and inherits its `__call()` overloading. Whereas block actions in layout XML call block methods, the following are possible:

Pass a string (and it can be translated!):

```
<action method="setSomeVal" translate="arg" module="some/helper">
    <arg>Some String</arg>
</action>
```

Pass an array:

```
<action method="setSomeVal">
    <arg>
        <key1>Some String</key1>
        <key2>Some String</key2>
        <key3>
            <multikey1>Some String</multikey1>
        </key3>
    </arg>
</action>
```

Pass anything you want:

```
<action method="setSomeVal">
    <arg helper="some/helper/method">
        <param_for_the_helper_method>
            <getting_crazy>Oh Boy.</getting_crazy>
        </param_for_the_helper_method>
</action>
```

Retrieve the value in the block/template with `$this->getSomeVal();`.

Fun, huh?

Comment: I was most unclear in my question it seems, I do apologise. Please see update. +1 for answer though.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the following :

```
<!-- in layout xml file -->
<action method="setData"><name>color_id</name><value>5</value></action>
```

Then, you can use in block file like below :

```
  $colors = $this->getColorId();
# or
  $colors = $this->getData('color_id');
```

Comment: I was most unclear in my question it seems, I do apologise. Please see update. +1 for answer though.